# The Group of order $p^3$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, prime-numbers, group-isomorphism

p is a prime number.

Let G be the Group of order $p^3$ whose every element in $G$ has order p.

Then G is not isomorphic to any subgroup of $GL(2; \mathbb{C})$.

This claim is correcet? Please help me.

Comment: The identity element in $G$ cannot have order $p$. So *every element different from the identity* having order $p$.

Comment: For odd $p$ there are two isomorphism classes of groups in which every nonidentity element has order $p$,one abelian and one nonabelian. Are you trying to prove this for both of these types of groups or only for one of them and,if so, which?

Comment: Since I had no idea, I have noticed that thing. I will consider both types.

Answer (score 4):

For $p=2$ there are exactly two non-abelian groups of order $p^3$, namely $D_4$ and $Q_8$, but both do not satisfy the assumption that all non-identity elements have order $p$. It remains the abelian group $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^3$.
For $p>2$ the [classification](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/groupsp3.pdf) given in Theorem $4$ shows, there are only *two* groups of order $p^3$ where all non-identity elements have order $p$, namely $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^3$ and $Heis(\mathbb{Z}/(p))$. Now the finite subgroups of $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$ are all classified, and the list easily shows that neither $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^3$ nor $Heis(\mathbb{Z}/(p))$ for any prime $p$ is a subgroup of $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Please tell me how to classfy  finite subgroups of GL(2,C).

Comment: See [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/55995/finite-subgroup-of-gl-2c) for references.

Comment: I didn't downvote. But at the time I made my comment, you had written that for $p=2$ there are only two groups of order $p^3$, and you have now edited it. I will delete my earlier comment and upvote!!!

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you. Yes, you are right, for $p=2$ I forgot to consider $C_{p^3}$.

Answer (score 3):

(1) $|G|=p^3$ and $G$ is *isomorphic* to subgroup of $GL({\bf 2},\mathbb{C})$.

(2) This means that there is a *faithful* **two** dimensional representation of $G$ 
over $\mathbb{C}$.

(3) If this representation is not irreducible, then it means, image of $G$ *essenntially* sits as block diagonal matrices $\begin{bmatrix} * & 0 \\ 0 & * \end{bmatrix}$.

(4) But such matrices can at the most form a group of order $p^2$ (i.e. such subgroup, being image of a $p$-group, has order $1$, $p$ or $p^2$). So $\rho$ will not be faithful ($|G|=p^3$ but order of image is not $p^3$), contradiction

(5) So $\rho$ should be *irreducible*.

(6) It is standard result in representation theory that the *dimension* of an irreducible representation should be a divisor of order of group. So here, $2$ should divide $p^3$.

(7) Conclusion: $p$ must be $2$. Follow arguments of Dietrich Brude, and try to write details.

Comment: Nice! I was gonna type up an argument using the normalizer of the diagonally embedded $C_p\times C_p$ inside $GL_2$ to reach the conclusion that we must have $p=2$. Representation theory FTW.