# Finite subgroup of $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I ask a question about finite subgroup of $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$.

I want to classfy the finite subgroup of $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$

(especially, subgroups of order $p^3$ , $p$ is prime number.)

Is it possible to classfy?

Comment: The list of finite subgroups of that group is well-known. Google should find you the list and the proofs easily! Try "finite subgroups of gl(2,c)"

Comment: What is the word that I should search using goolge?

Comment: "finite subgroups of gl(2,c)", unsurprisingly (wrap the words between quote marks)

Comment: Is this information from google search only SL(2,C)?   Of course, it contains SL(2,C).  But, I think it doesn't contain GL(2,C).

Comment: See [this MO-question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/55995/finite-subgroup-of-gl-2c) for references.

Comment: It follows from the arguments in the answers to [your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2162430/11619) that a subgroup of $GL_2(\Bbb{C})$ of order $p^3$ is either abelian, or $p=2$. Is that clear to you, or do you want it detailed?

Comment: I want details just in case.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is a finite subgroup of $\rm{GL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ then we can state this as *there is a homomorphism (representation) $\rho:G\rightarrow \rm{GL}(2,\mathbb{C})$*.

It is a standard result that this representation we can look *into* subgroup $U(2,\mathbb{C})$ of unitary matrices (See, Artin's Algebra).

So, your question reduces to finding finding finite subgroups of $U(2,\mathbb{C})$. This has been well studied.

For example, in *Complex Functions by Jones and Singerman*, the beginning chapter is devoted to study of finite subgroups of this group. Since the complete proof is very long, it is appropriate here just to mention its source.